# Restricting a representation to a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

This little factoid from algebra quals stumped me: Let $G$ be a finite group and $H \triangleleft G$ an index $2$ subgroup. If we take an irreducible complex representation $V$ of $G$ and restrict it to $H$, it may not remain irreducible. However, show that the restriction of an irreducible representation is irreducible if any two elements in $H$ which are conjugate in $G$ remain conjugate in $H$.

Comment: This is one part of Problem 5.2 on page 65 of Fulton and Harris. They provide a hint I think (it's starred.) You have to also use the proposition they prove before.